# HTML5 Canvas: Thousand of moving Images = Huge FPS loss

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I'm trying to build an HTML5 Game with Canvas 2D (Only for Computer as device). But there's a Problem, I have thousands of moving images and with around 4000+ Images (Enemys) I dont get more then 10 FPS. With Java2D it's working fine, now I'm trying to import the Game to HTML5. Did anyone have some tips to realize this in HTML5? Some Code optimization? For any help I would be very grateful.

http://jsfiddle.net/LtlFdl/tzd8z/

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 320); // <- Maybe just Clear the Enemy Square Position?
```

btw.: on the Fiddle is just ONE playerfield, at the end there 4 playerfields (rotated 90, 180 and 270 degress), a background image, towers and a lot of effects. So I have to multiple everything with 4.

Comment: I'm seeing a few instances of ctx.save and ctx.restore with nothing in between that I'm noticing to take advantage of that. I also note that each enemy has the same image loaded. Sure, the browser will cache the download, but I'm not so sure that it will cache the decoded image that results, ergo: you're decoding the (same) image for each enemy. Lastly, is it your intention to call `Update_Map1` 100 times a second?

Comment: Just forgot to remove the instances of save & restore for the post here, the original code have something between. To decode the image only once is a good idea, thanks. The Interval of 10ms is just for the test, around 17ms is normal for something like 60 FPS. Thank you!

Comment: A few things : 1) By using requestAnimationFrame, you'll instantly gain smoothness, since setInterval might tick when video buffer is not available, hence adding further delay. 2) be sure not to console.log when you're measuring precisely performances. You might rather fillText the value for a much smaller performance hit. 3) store once and for all all your often used const strings in vars ('#000'=black, ...) because you're creating garbage that you can easily avoid ( 2 * fps * string length * enemy count bytes per second =4MB here). 4) do not use delete but rather an 'alive' flag.

Comment: 1. Yeah of course, normally I use rAF, idk why I changed it to a timer. There's another problem, its a multiplayer and I don't want that the Enemys stop when anyone change the tab or minimize the Browser.   2. I comment it out when I test something, it was just this time but thanks    3. Its simple but never thought about this, thank you dude!    4. What is an alive Flag?

Comment: (use @username: to be sure people get notified.) 1) no solution for this : you have to handle gracefully a user tabbing out (setInterval /timeout will stop also)... 2) OK. 3) you're welcome, it might smoothen things a tiny bit. 4) i'm talking about a boolean, markE suggests quite the same thing, i saw.

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Thanks for this tip. 1.) Okay thats bad, but okay. 3.) yh I'll hope so.. 4.) yh got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First...Ditto the good thoughts that @enhzflep has already mentioned in his comment.

I would add that setting the fillStyle is a somewhat expensive operation so setting the fillStyle with each of 4000 Enemy draws becomes very expensive.  I suggest that you just display the textual & health info once per second rather than with each Update_Map1.

On my modestly fast development desktop I can do 4000 X drawImage(img,0,0) at a rate of 45 times per second.  This leads me to believe the transformations (translate,rotate) are slowing you down.  Perhaps create 4 versions of your enemy image--facing up,down,left & right.  Then entirely replace the transforms by drawing the appropriately facing image.

I see you're using `delete Enemys_P1[i]`. It's more resource effective to "recycle" exiting enemies.  You can do this by marking an Enemy as "inactive" and not processing that enemy. When you need a new enemy you can change an inactive enemy to "active" and set its properties to the "new" enemy values.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: To display the textual only once is enough. But display the health info once is'nt enough, then it will not be fixed on the enemy, its more like a laggy health bar then. To create more then one Image is a nice idea too, just a sprite maybe. How can I set something to inactive? Just hide it and dont move it anymore? Thank you!

Comment: The idea is to not change the context state very often.  Perhaps create a 2nd tiny canvas that only displays the text and health and overlay this 2nd canvas over the main canvas.  To recycle an object just add an "isActive" property to the object.  If isActive==true then draw the object, otherwise don't draw it. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I did this some hours ago with 2 canvas over each other, the Background, Buttons and Text are on the one who did not get redrawed. So the enemys never stops but an isActive var is usefull for the dead enemys, thanks.